# redux-form remove function doesn't work

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a strange problem with my form. I can add and remove fields with two several buttons, but the remove button has stopped working. I can see that on clicking still the action "@@redux-form/ARRAY_REMOVE" gets fired, but the field does not disappear. I don't really know why it stopped working, I tried to undo all the code I wrote afterwards, but wasn't able to track the error down. Would appreciate any input. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import validate from './validate';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin(); //Needed, otherwise an error message is shown in the console

const renderTextField = ({input, label, meta: {touched, error}, ...custom}) => (
  <TextField
    hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
);

const renderUsers = ({fields, meta: { touched, error }}) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary"
              type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"/> Add User
      </button>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>

    {fields.map((index) =>
    <div key={index}>

        <Field name={`${index}.firstName`} component={renderTextField} label="First Name"/>

        <Field name={`${index}.lastName`} component={renderTextField} label="Last Name"/>

        <Field name={`${index}.position`} component={renderTextField} label="Position"/>

        <Field name={`${index}.email`} component={renderTextField} label="Email"/>

        <button className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                type="button"
                title="Remove User"
                onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"/>
        </button>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
);

const UserCreation = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <FieldArray name="users" component={renderUsers}/>

      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-success"
                type="submit"
                disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send" />
          Submit
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-danger"
                disabled={ pristine || submitting}
                onClick={reset}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'UserCreationForm',
  validate
})(UserCreation);
```

Here is a snapshot from my console when I try to remove the field:

[console.log of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGuyV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I added a second key to the map function:

```
{fields.map((user, index) =>
    <div key={index}>

        <Field name={`${user}.firstName`} component={renderTextField} label="First Name"/>

        <Field name={`${user}.lastName`} component={renderTextField} label="Last Name"/>

        <Field name={`${user}.position`} component={renderTextField} label="Position"/>

        <Field name={`${user}.email`} component={renderTextField} label="Email"/>
```